# Topshelf service not running automatically after first execution completes

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

I have a service which should run after every time it finishes, But topshelf hosted windows service runs one time when I start it but never run again?

Do I need to configure something.

My current configuration is

```
namespace RL.Reprice
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            HostFactory.Run(serviceConfig =>
            {
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
                serviceConfig.UseLog4Net();

                serviceConfig.Service<RepriceBook>(serviceInstance =>
                {
                    serviceInstance.ConstructUsing(
                        () => new RepriceBook());

                    serviceInstance.WhenStarted(
                        execute => execute.Start());

                    serviceInstance.WhenStopped(
                        execute => execute.Stop());

                    //    serviceInstance.WhenPaused(
                    //        execute => execute.Pause());

                    //    serviceInstance.WhenContinued(
                    //        execute => execute.Continue());
                });

                serviceConfig.EnableServiceRecovery(recoveryOption =>
                {
                    recoveryOption.RestartService(2);
                });

                serviceConfig.SetServiceName("RepriceService");
                serviceConfig.SetDisplayName("Reprice Book");
                serviceConfig.SetDescription("This is Repricer");

                serviceConfig.StartAutomatically();
            });                                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean it runs once? When you run it, are you saying there is a task within the service that needs to be executed by itself repeatedly and it only gets executed once?

Comment: Yes, Service has a task, which needs to run after first execution. I am not looping it, considering windows service does this automatically

Comment: @Stackedup I am reading data from db and processing it, sometimes there is no data service should stop, when data is there it should run again.

Comment: I don't believe so. It will execute once. You need to use something within there to re-run the task.

Comment: Ok, so do you have some sort of trigger there? like an event listener?

Comment: @Stackedup So, How bad is to use while(true) loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195844/discussion-between-tbag-and-stackedup).

Comment: you could use...Timer instead

Answer (score 0):

Use [Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) to run the task repeatedly.